# maps api v3 google.maps.event.addListener(?,event, fn) for a thousand polygons

Tags: events, google-maps-api-3

I have more than a thousand of polygons loaded into my map and I don't want to attach addListener to every single one.

So how can I use google.maps.event.addListener(?,event, fn) to get this working?

Comment: How are these polygons loaded?  Are they KML?  Image overlays?  What?  Can you show the code?

Comment: Hi Trott, they r all google.maps.Polygons:

mun_map[1500347] = new PLG({ paths: mun_1500347_co}); mun_map[1500347].setOptions(m_op); mun_map[1500347].setMap(map);

Comment: Trott, using earth api, adding an eventlistener to onmouseover, I use event.getTarget().getType() to determine type, and getName added to event.getTarget()  to get elements name... don't know how to do it using maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weel, it seems to be impossible.
So, I created a function to instantiate each polygon, attacching  google.maps.event.addListener($polygon,event, fn) to each one of them.
thx!